# Subquery in mysql looking for in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have one table with this headers

```
id city date item
```

I am interested in identify the id with the same item in the same month and count how many items repeated receive in the same month. So my query in mysql is:

```
select a.id, concat(a.id, month(a.date), a.item) as a from table
 where a = (select concat(b.id, month(b.date), b.item) as b from table)
 group by a.id
having count(a=b)>=1
```

But that query take too much time and may not work, could you help me?

Comment: Isn't `id` the unique ID that identifies a record? Its name seems to imply this. In this case there can be no two occurences for the same `id` - each `id` is unique in the table.

Comment: put the table data, or structure

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense and I am surprised it doesn't result in a syntax error (the alias b should not be known outside the subquery and hence not available in the having clause. Edit your requerst and show sample data and the expected result.

Comment: I am sorry, @ThorstenKettner I new on this. The id is not really unique because represent the identification from a user that receive any item in different months

Comment: So it's a very bad column name. However, do the answers given solve your problem? If yes, accept one, if not, clarify your question by adding sample data and the desired result, so we finally know what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't reacted to the comments made three hours ago. But from your comments to Seth McClaine's answer I read that you want a list of rows showing id (*which despite its name is not the table's unique ID!*), month, item, and the number of occurences.

One row per id, month and item means: `group by id, month, item`.

Use a `HAVING` clause in order to only show occurences > 1.

```
select id, month(date), item, count(*)
from mytable
group by id, month(date), item
having count(*) > 1;
```

Well, this is about what Seth McClaine already told you. And while you commented on his answer, you didn't say what is missing from it for you to accept it.

Comment: thank you @Thorsten Kettner for the answer, I imagine that would need it a more complicated query. This part of my life is called happiness!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something like this, giving you the count `total` of items with matching `id`, `month`, and `item`

```
Select Count(*) as total,  month(date) as month, item, id 
From table
group by (item,  month(date), id)
```

Comment: in the question, the user wrote: "same month"

Comment: nice! but if id is unique this example not work. is not fully understood as using the id.

Comment: I agree, but base on the OPs potentially "working example" they are not using the id as unique. I would assume the id is to describe the item and not a primary key

Comment: |  id   | city | date  | item to give an example following the order of headers the dates are: row 1: 1 | bogota | 2016-10-01| 2 ; row 2: 2| cali | 2016-02| 1; row 3: 1 | bogota | 2016-10-12 | 2. I need the case when the id 1 that repeat in different dates receive the same item in the same month. For the example he/she receive the item 2 in october so I need a query that show that differents id and the number of times that item appear in the same month.

Comment: @YanethGil in your example, you have repeating ids that correlate to your items, they are all going to be the same id.

Comment: @SethMcClaine, yes I want to know the items that repeat for the same user that is identified with the same id

Comment: that query not work for me because doesn't identify the items duplicates by id in the same month

Comment: your ids are the same